# How to use parent class, in Toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

I defined a GeneralFrame class that inherits from tk.LabelFrame, which contains other widgets like labels and entries:

```
class GeneralFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, eCount, lCount):
        super().__init__()

        self.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
        self.entry_widget(eCount)
        self.label_widget(lCount)
      

    def entry_widget(self, eCount):
        self.e = {}
        for i in range(0, eCount):
            self.e[i] = tk.Entry(self, width=6)
            self.e[i].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='w')
            self.e[i].delete(0, tk.END)

    def label_widget(self, lCount):
        self.l = {}
        for i in range(0, lCount):
            self.l[i] = tk.Label(self)
            self.l[i].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w')
```

How can I use this class in a TopLevel window?
I've tried like this but it places the frame_save in parent window not TopLevel:

```
def openNewWindow():
    newWindow = Toplevel(window)
    newWindow.title('Saved Data')
    newWindow.geometry('200x200')

    frame_save = GeneralFrame(newWindow, eCount=5, lCount=5)
    frame_save.configure(text='Saved data',font=("Helvetica",14,"bold"))
    frame_save.grid(row=0, column=0)

    labels_text = ['label1','label2','label3','label4','label5']
    [frame_save.l[i].configure(text=labels_text[i]) for i in range(0,5)]
```

And general use in parent window:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("980x500")
window.resizable(1,1)
window.title('Calculator')

class GeneralFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
[code]

frame_1 = GeneralFrame(window, eCount=5, lCount=5)
frame_2 = GeneralFrame(window, eCount=5, lCount=5)

def Frame_1():
 [code]
def Frame_2():
 [code]

Frame_1()
Frame_2()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your LabelFrame subclass did not pass on the `master` parameter when calling `super().__init__()`, therefore it became a child of the root window by default.

Comment: Like said above, you need to: `super().__init__(self,master)`

Comment: If I do that, I get an error:AttributeError: 'GeneralFrame' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: @Adrian Sorry my bad, it should've been `super().__init__(master)`. But you're answer works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `master` when calling `super().__init__`. Otherwise, the actual frame has a default master, and the default master is the root window.

```
super().__init__(master)
```

Also, I encourage you to *not* call `self.grid` inside the `__init__`. The way tkinter widgets are designed, it's expected that the code that creates the widgets also calls `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the widget. Otherwise your class can only ever be used in a parent that uses `grid`.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I do this:

```
class GeneralFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, eCount, lCount):
        #super().__init__()
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self,master)
```